# how to collect all information about the current Job in Talend data studio

Tags: mongodb, talend

I'm Running any job then I want to log all information like ---

1. job name
2. Source detail and destination details (file name/Table name)
3. No of records input and number of records processed or save.
   so I want log all the above information and insert into Mongodb using talend open studio Components also explain what component do I need to perform that task. need some serious response thanks.
   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tJava component as below. Get the count of source, destination, details of the source name and target name. Now redirect the details to a file in tJava.

[image]

For more about logging functionalities, go through below tutorials,

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SSi8BC58v3k&list=PL2eC8CR2B2qfgDaQtUs4Wad5u-70ala35&index=2

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider using log4j which has most of this information. Using MDC you could expand the log messages with custom attributes. Log4j does have a JSON format, and there seems to be a MongoDB appender as well.

It might take a bit more time to configure (I'd suggest adding the dependencies via a routine) but once configured it will require absolutely no configuration in the job. Using log4j you can create filters, etc.